# ERC-1155 contract verification error: Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI | ByteCode (what we are looking for): - vs what we got -

Tags: solidity, erc-1155, contract-verification

I'm getting the following error while verifying my ERC-1155 smart contracts.

Before verifying I cross-checked the following things:

- compiler version.
- Optimizer settings (enabled or not, runs, etc.)
- Solidity code.
- All the libraries are imported correctly (flattened the OZ contracts in remix to have a single solidity file before deploying)

*Note: my constructor doesn't have any arguments.*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You Probably missing out on constructor parameters.

Look out does contract have constructor parameters.

Give parameters in 64 characters, add zeros as padding.

Check constructor parameters like this https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0x11f7f73a70bb161f4f0ca7d74920b374c80f8cde#code